# selecting multiple paths in d3js

Tags: d3.js, transition

I have changed this code from Mike Bostocks [arc tween](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636), to make it multiple arc tween.I want to select each arc and animate them individually with unique value. What i have done now is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3yz/)

```
setInterval(function() {
  foregrounds.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, degToRad(getRandomRange(-150,150)));                  
}, 1500);
```

where i am having confusion is in the selection part.`'foregrounds'` selection consists of 3 arcs and when i transition this all the arc are transitioned but the animation is very insignificant.And also i want to animate these arc individually with unique value. What do i have to do here? using ids for each path and transition them using loop or there must be some method in d3js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `degToRad` in this case -- the arc generator does that conversion for you. If you remove it, you should see bigger changes. To have separate changes for each arc, simply compute the angle inside `arcTween` and not at the top level:

```
function arcTween(transition) {
  transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, getRandomRange(-150,150));
    return function(t) {
      d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
      return arc(d);
    };
  });
}
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3yz/1/).

Comment: thank you very much. but why not degToRad. i have included it while animating a single arc and it is working but in three arcs the animation is insignificant?

Comment: You're interpolating between angles specified in degrees, so there's no need to convert to rad.